# Convert adjacency list to enumeration path ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, enumeration, adjacency-list

How can I create a procedure that converts an adjacency list to enumeration path in Oracle (by creating a new table as an enumeration path)? The adjacency list is a table that looks like this:

```
AdjList(id number, parent_id number, name varchar2)

ID PARENT_ID  NAME
-----------------------------
1             CATEGORY1
2    1        PROD1
3             CATEGORY2
4    3        PROD2
5    4        SUBPROD1
```

Desired output:

```
EnumPath(id number, parent_id number, name varchar2, path varchar2)

ID PARENT_ID  NAME          PATH
-----------------------------------
1             CATEGORY1     /1/
2    1        PROD1         /1/2/
3             CATEGORY2     /3/
4    3        PROD2         /3/4/
5    4        SUBPROD1      /3/4/5/
```

Comment: Sample data and desired output, please.

Comment: @Littlefoot I've added more specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a `sys_connect_by_path` hierarchical query to me.

```
SQL> with test (id, parent_id, name) as
  2    (select 1, null, 'category1' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 1   , 'prod1' from dual union all
  4     select 3, null, 'category2' from dual union all
  5     select 4, 3   , 'prod2' from dual union all
  6     select 5, 4   , 'subprod1' from dual
  7    )
  8  select id, parent_id, name,
  9    ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(id, '>'), '>') path
 10  from test
 11  connect by prior id = parent_id
 12  start with parent_id is null;

        ID  PARENT_ID NAME      PATH
---------- ---------- --------- --------------------
         1            category1 1
         2          1 prod1     1>2
         3            category2 3
         4          3 prod2     3>4
         5          4 subprod1  3>4>5

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without data it's difficult to say, but if you've got data similar to

```
ID    PARENT_ID    NAME
1     NULL         TOP
2     1            L2
3     2            L3
4     3            BOTTOM
```

and you're looking for something like

```
TOP -> L2 -> L3 -> BOTTOM
```

you could use a query such as

```
SELECT LISTAGG(NAME, ' -> ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY LEVEL) AS PATH
  FROM ADJLIST
  CONNECT BY PARENT_ID = PRIOR ID
  START WITH ID = (SELECT ID FROM ADJLIST WHERE PARENT_ID IS NULL)
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=302e6b6c1d67fed09ad978f9004793f0)

Comment: @Anaidm: take the sample query and modify it to get your desired output.

Comment: But what if I have more parent ids that are null (roots)? Also, I would like to know the path for each record.

Comment: `SELECT LISTAGG(ID, ' -> ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY LEVEL) AS PATH
  FROM ADJLIST
  CONNECT BY PARENT_ID = PRIOR ID
  START WITH ID IS NULL` it gives me empty path.

Comment: ID is never NULL.